# Customize JSON retrieved from mysql

Tags: mysql, json

Lets say this is my database table

```
id    ProductID    color      size
1      abc           red        L
2      abc           green      M
3      abc           yellow     S
4      def           purple     L
5      def           brown      M
6      def           pink       S
```

Now I am fecthing data using my sql queires but in response i want my json in this structure

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "All Product Logs has been fetched Successfully",
    "products": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "ProductID": "abc",
            "colors": [
                   "red",
                   "green",
                   "yellow",
                    ],
            "sizes": [
                   "L",
                   "M",
                   "S",
                    ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "ProductID": "def",
            "colors": [
                   "purple",
                   "brown",
                   "pink",
                    ],
            "sizes": [
                   "L",
                   "M",
                   "S",
                    ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this what i do but it doesn't makes sense

```
   if ($response) {
   $JSONDataArray=[];
   $ColorDataArray=[];
   $SizeDataArray=[];
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){

   $ColorDataArray[]=array($row['color']);
   $SizeDataArray[]=array($row['size']);
   $JSONDataArray[]=array('productid' =>$row['productid'],'color' => $ColorDataArray,'sizes' => $SizeDataArray);
   }
        echo json_encode(['status'=>true,'message'=>'All Products has been fetched Successfully','products'=>$JSONDataArray]);
}
```

Anykind of help would be appreciated. What do u think should i change my database structure or should i change my query. I simply user `Select *` query without any where clause

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: the latest one...mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) function:

```sql
SELECT JSON_PRETTY(
  CONCAT(
    '{"status": true, ',
    '"message": "All Product Logs has been fetched Successfully", ',
    '"products": [',
    (
      SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(`der`.`json`)
      FROM (
        SELECT
          JSON_OBJECT(
            'ProductID', `ProductID`,
            'colors', JSON_ARRAYAGG(`color`),
            'sizes', JSON_ARRAYAGG(`size`)
          ) `json`
        FROM
          `tbl`
        GROUP BY
          `ProductID`
      ) `der`
    ),
    ']}'
  )
) `json_response`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=510f7454f8d76425a7d82822cefbbeda).

Keep in mind: [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat): The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the [group_concat_max_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) system variable.